# How to add Authorization Bearer to Socket Client

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, socket.io, bearer-token

I have a software which uses socketio communication. Backend added an access token to access the events. I need to implement Bearer Auth to my socket client python file. I checked the SocketIO Documentation bot I cannot find how to implement Bearer Token. How to make it?

```
import socketio
import json
import requests
import uuid

accessToken = "Bearer (mytoken)"
value = ""

qrid = uuid.uuid4()
uuid = uuid.uuid4()

url = 'myurl'

myobj = {
  "qrid": str(qrid),
  "uuid": str(uuid)
}
sio = socketio.Client()



@sio.on('connect', namespace='/mynamespace')
def connect():
    print("connected")
    create = requests.post(url, json = myobj)
    print(create.text)
    sio.emit("joinClient", str(id), namespace='/mynamespace')

@sio.on('disconnect', namespace='/mynamespace')
def disconnect():
    print('disconnected')

@sio.on("room", namespace='/mynamespace')
def a(data):
    print('received:', data)
    eventType = (json.loads(json.dumps(data))["eventType"])
    
   
    if eventType == "openevent":
        value = (json.loads(json.dumps(data))["value"])
        if value == True:
            print("open")
        else:
            print("don't open")
    else:
        print(eventType)
    
# --- main ---


print('start')
sio.sleep(1)
sio.connect('wss://myurl', namespaces=['/mynamespace'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `connect` method takes a `headers` argument. You can add an `Authorization` header there, like so:

```
sio.connect('wss://myurl', headers={'Authorization': accessToken}, ...)
```

[Reference for Client.connect](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#socketio.Client.connect)

[More about the Authorization header in general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)